# React-Native-Swipeout custom button with icon

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-swipeout and it's working fine.  I can create an function to add an icon but using an incline function does not work.  I get no error but the icon does not display.  For example:

```
var buttons = [{
text: 'Delete', 
component: this.icon('trash'), 
backgroundColor: '#ff0000', 
onPress: function() {self.pcDelete(data)}}
];

icon(iconName) {
    return ( <Entypo name={iconName} size={30}/> )
}
```

The code above works.  The code below does not display the icon, in fact Entypo does not get executed at all.

```
var buttons = [{
text: 'Delete', 
component: function() { return ( <Entypo name={iconName} size={30}/> )  },
backgroundColor: '#ff0000', 
onPress: function() {self.pcDelete(data)}}
];
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: I've seen that returned when the <Text> has an empty string. Have you tried  wrapping a component instead of text. <Entypo name='<newcomponentIcon/>' size={20}/>

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I've made some progress and updated the post.

Answer (score 7):

***Here is Full Example***

```
class SwipeoutExample extends Component {

  render() {
    const swipeBtns = [
      {
        component: (
          <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                flexDirection: 'column',
              }}
          >
            <Image source={require('../../../../../images/delete_white.png')} />
          </View>
        ),
        backgroundColor: colors.bitterSweetBorder,
        underlayColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1, 0.6)',
        onPress: () => {
          console.log("Delete Item");
        },
      },
    ];

    return (
        <Swipeout
            right={swipeBtns}
            autoClose="true"
            backgroundColor="transparent"
        >
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cartItem} onPress={this.onItemClick}>

          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Swipeout>
    );
  }
}
```

[Swipe_to_Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BExAB.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to just remove the text and replace it with component. Here is the example:

```
let swipeoutBtns = [
  {
    component:
      (
        <View>
          <Icon style={styles.icon} name='shopping-cart'/>
        </View>
      )
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to find the answer to this as well, but [one of the files in the github repo for react-native-swipeout](https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout/blob/master/example/data.js) shows you how to do it. Based on that example, the below code works for me:

```
component: <Image source={{uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/BlackStar.PNG'}} style={{width: 30, height: 30}} />
```